# Install Python3 on Node Alpine Docker Image

Tags: python, node.js, image, dockerfile, apk

I used this Docker file to create an environment for my service:

```
FROM node:16.13.2-alpine as packages
WORKDIR /src
ARG NPM_TKE

COPY .npmrc package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
COPY ./cucumber.testing.js ./cucumber.js

RUN npm run swagger
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm","run","integration-test" ]
```

I installed new package on my service that throws the exception below (it asked for Python).
[Python Error Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8EEe.png)

Locally, I have installed Python and use npm set config to define Python's ENV PATH - and locally, that works good! Now I need it to work on my docker image (:

I tried to install python on my node docker image, which means adding a command to my docker file, but I ran into a different exception. For example:

```
FROM node:16.13.2-alpine as packages
RUN apk add python3 //*** ADDED ***
WORKDIR /src
ARG NPM_TKE

COPY .npmrc package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
COPY ./cucumber.testing.js ./cucumber.js

RUN npm run swagger
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm","run","integration-test" ]
```

[Error after adding "RUN apk add python3" #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZRGm.png)
[Error after adding "RUN apk add python3" #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpYVj.png)

I saw errors about missing 'make', 'g++', etc., and tried this command instead of the last one, but got other different errors:

```
RUN apk update && apk add python3 make g++ 
# OR
RUN apk add --no-cache python3
```

[Error after adding "RUN apk update && apk add python3 make g++" #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCTxx.png)
[Error after adding "RUN apk update && apk add python3 make g++" #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcgl4.png)

What is the problem here? How can I install python on my docker image?

Answer (score 0):

After checking the error log you provided, it looks like this error has nothing to do with python. Instead, it was raised by the `node-segfault-handler` package, and there's an open issue on its repo [here](https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler/issues/70).
You might want to track this down to see if any updates or find an alternative package since this issue remains open status for two years